# Using PageView with Bloc to programmatically 'swipe' pages. Prevent the bloc builder from building on certain states?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-pageview, cubit

I've built a `PageView` and want to control page swiping programmatically using a `Bloc`.

I'm using a `PageController` and listening for my bloc's `ShowPage` state. Then calling `pageController.animateTo` to animate the `PageView` to the desired page.

The bloc builder builds the PageView.

I suspect the problem I'm having is caused by the `BlocBuilder` building a new `PageView` on every state change and thus negating the `pageController.animateTo`.

My question is firstly ... can the `BlockBuilder` be prevented from firing/building for certain states (so it doesn't 'overwrite' my `pageController` changes).
or
Is there a better (correct) way of implementing a `PageView` with bloc?

I've copied the screen code the basic cubit below for info.

```
    class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 4);
  double page = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<TestCubit, TestState>(listener: (context, state) async {
      if (state is DeviceLogsInitial) {
        await _animateTo(3);
      }
      if (state is ShowPage) {
        await _animateTo(state.page);
      }
    }, builder: (context, state) {
     // _log.info('Building dialog : page ${_pageController.page}');
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Test'),// ${_pageController.page}'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  page = _nextPage(page);
                  BlocProvider.of<TestCubit>(context).animate(page);
                },
                child: const Text('swipe'))
          ],
        ),
        body: PageView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _pageController,
          children: const [
            Page0(),
            Page1(),
            Page2(),
            Page3(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  double _nextPage(double page) {
    if (page > 3) {
      page = 0;
    } else {
      page = page + 1;
    }
    return page;
  }

  Future<void> _animateTo(double _page) async {
    _pageController.animateTo(
      _page,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

class TestCubit extends Cubit<TestState> {
  TestCubit() : super(TestInitial());

  Future<void> animate(double page) async {
    emit(ShowPage(page));
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you are using the `flutter_bloc` package, it provides a build when method where you have control to rebuild or not, have you tried that ?

Comment: That's a great call thank you. A feature that I wasn't aware of and will use in the future.  However my issue seems to have been caused simply by me not calling the correct `PageController` method. I should be calling `pageController.animateToPage` ! 
(The documentation and 'tutorials' are particularly bad on this) . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah ! glad you caught it. I do that myself a lot of times but when I start posting a question on this forum I will sometimes find a hint to the solution, guess its some sort of rubber duck programming :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a case of using the wrong `PageController` method for animating between pages.

The method you should be calling is `pageController.animateToPage` and not `pageController.animateTo`.

You could also use `jumpToPage` if you didn't require animation (and not `jumpTo` which would cause a similar issue).